# What is the use of hypen(-) in java

Tags: java, arrays

Can some one explain what `runner.children[c-'a']`
means in the following code.

```
public boolean search(String word) {
    TrieNode runner = root;
    for(char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        if(runner.children[c-'a'] == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            runner = runner.children[c-'a'];
        }
    }
    return runner.isEndOfWord;
}
```

Comment: That's not a hyphen; that's a *minus*.

Comment: `'a'` which is ascii 97, so it's `c - 97`.

Answer (score 2):

Every `char` has a numeric value, check out [the ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for more information.

So assume that the variable `c` contains character *b*, and subtract character *a* from that, you will get *1* for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's just subtraction. You can subtract characters as though they were numbers. You end up with the result of subtracting their character codes. `'c' - 'a'` (for example) equals 2, since `'a'` is 2 less than `'c'`.

Answer (score 1):

`-` is the subtraction operator.

[§15.18.2 The type of each of the operands of the binary - operator must be a type that is convertible to a primitive *numeric* type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

[§5.6.2 Widening primitive conversion is applied to convert either or both operands … both operands are converted to type int.
Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators: … addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and -  …](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

In other words, both `c` and `'a'` are of type `char` (a UTF-16 code unit, which has a range from [Character.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_VALUE) to [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE)). Due to subtraction, they are widened to type `int`, subtracted, resulting in a value of type `int`.

Think of characters on a number line. Subtraction is the distance from one character to the other. With a constant reference to `'a'`, the distances for `'a'`, `'b'`, … `'z'` are 0, 1, … 25. This makes sense only over certain short segments of the UTF-16 number line.

Arrays are 0-based so shifting the scale like this allows characters to be used to index an array without having a large used portion with elements corresponding to unused characters.

(Note: Some people are saying ASCII because they think it's easier to understand a simpler, wrong thing on the way to learning the right thing. )

Answer (score 0):

In this case children[] is probably the size of the amount of letters from a-z.

What is going on above is that they take the ascii value of the char c, and subtracting the ascii code of 'a'. Effectively resulting in getting the index of the char c in the alphabet (0-Index assumed)

Let c = 'b'

```
[c-'a'] = 98 - 97 = 1 (Ascii of b - Ascii of a)
```

With c = 'd'

```
[c-'a'] = 100 - 97 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `minus` sign and not hyphen. In java char takes 2 bytes of space. char is representation of bits ranging from 00000000 to 11111111, most significant bit is read as signed bit. You can easily read it as a number also by assiging a char to an int variable ( as int can accept 4 bytes so 2 bytes of char can easily fit ).

```
char charA = ''A'; // represents 65
char charB = `B`; // represents 66
int diff = charB - charA; // this will represent 66-65 i.e. 1
```

Index of the array is positve int and hence it can also accept values like

```
anyTypeArray[charB - charA] //represents the 2nd element (index starts from 0 for arrays in java).

anyTypeArray['C' - charA] // represents the 3rd element of the array
```

Also I liked answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106997/504133 and would like to add its link to extend my answer.